# Turn off Plural Names with xjc simple binding mode

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf, xjc

I have an XSD that I'd like to not change to solve the problem I'll describe below. With the XSD in it's current form, I ran into the common problem of no `@XmlRootlement` being generated, and used the [simple binding mode solution](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/03/03/why-does-jaxb-put-xmlrootelement-sometimes-not-always) pointed out by many to get this annotation added.

Unfortunately, this has caused some object names in the generated code to become pluralized (i.e. list/collection objects now become cars instead of car or donkies instead of donkey) which is not desirable as I'm using these objects to binding incoming requests in CXF. Is there anyway to use the simple binding mode but disable the pluralization?

Comment: Why are the pluralised names a problem? They don't change the XML element names, just the java property names.

Comment: However XJC team could have done each improvement as a separate option, what they didn't do. This kind of issue is good candidate for [JAXB JIRA](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB).

Comment: It may not modify the XML element names, but when I generated json responses from the same objects, the attribute names have been pluralized :(